# command 'rails server' doesn't work, cmd throws error with bootsnap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, localhost, puma

I have created project in path: D:\Сайты\ruby\lr5. When I am trying to launch it by command *rails server* it throws this error:

```
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:60:in `fetch': No such file or directory - bs_fetch:open_current_file:open (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:60:in `fetch'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:85:in `load_iseq'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:137:in `block in perform'
        from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.15.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I was trying to uninstall bootsnap, which has been download automatically with *gem install rails*, and install it manually, but it didn't give any positive result.
My OS is Windows 10 Home
My Ruby version is 3.1.0
I have downloaded Ruby from official by executable file (name is 'rubyinstaller-devkit-3.1.3-1-x64.exe'). Then I have installed gems MySQL and rails.

P.s Sorry for my english <3

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution!

- First problem: You can't use russian symbols in your path.
- Second problem: In your Gemfile, it must be written this `gem "tzinfo-data"` (without requirements).

Comment: The 2nd one is misleading. Putting explicit version constraints into the `Gemfile` is a common practice and removing the constraints should be carefully thought - there might be reasons why the constraint was there (breaking changes in newer versions for example)